# open modal in Bootstrap container on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm using a Bootstrap modal to show a progress bar while many gallery thumbnail images preload. The modal works fine, automatically opening when the page loads and hiding when the preload is complete. However, the modal darkens the entire screen - instead I want to leave the Navbar visible and just darken everything else. I'm using shuffle.js to sort and display gallery images when clicked, and for some reason it displays the modal in the way I want, but I can't figure out why and reverse engineer a solution. Here's what I have currently:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close" onclick="document.getElementById('myModal').style.display='none'">&times;</span>
  <img class="modal-content" id="img01">
  <div id="caption"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: very sry i cannot see the code , can u please attach your  full code?

Comment: OK. I've added the modal code. There's also a lot of php and javascript, but I don't think it's relevant. Unless you think I should post it anyway?

Comment: i have given my answer below,check whether it is useful or do u need more clarification,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap uses `modal-backdrop` class for Modal with z-index 1040, so you can set your navbar position to Relative and it's z-index more than 1040.

```
.yourNavbarClass{ 
 position:relative;
 z-index:1200;
 }
```

Comment: Setting the relative position messed up my page formatting, but when I deleted position:relative, it seems to work. Not the solution I was expecting, but thanks!

Comment: @KerimYagmurcu yes, we can use z-index with fixed, relative, absolute and sticky position.

Comment: Well I am facing issues on Firefox with modals and bootstrap 4 as most of the native functions like backdrop and fading effects don't work fine with sticked navigations... It's a firefox thing I guess :) @jumahMohammadi

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with bootstrap 4?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/0qf43vdn/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div id="myModal" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, Bootstrap 4. I amended my question with the modal code. Note I omitted the progress bar, as I haven't finished formatting it yet, and I didn't think it was relevant anyway. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

is This the answer you are expecting. displaying div in front even when the bootstrap model is open. by setting position fixed and z-index greater than model you would achive this. please look at the code be

> This is just a example you can change the code as you want

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
});
```

```css
#textfront{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="textfront">
<h1>
this text will be visible even when model is shown
</h1>
</div>


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```